# What is the function of const specifier in enum types?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, constants, language-lawyer

```
enum foo : const unsigned int
{
    F,
    S,
    T
};

void func()
{
    foo p;
    p = F;
}
```

The above compiles so the underlying type is not a const type?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `const` qualifier is ignored in the specification of [enum-base](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum); which just expects an integral type to be used as the underlying type of the enumeration type, specifying `const` (or `volatile`) doesn't make much sense.

(emphasis mine)

> colon (:), followed by a type-specifier-seq that names an integral type (**if it is cv-qualified, qualifications are ignored**) that will serve as the fixed underlying type for this enumeration type

From the standard, [[dcl.enum]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#2):

(emphasis mine)

> The [*type-specifier-seq*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type#nt:type-specifier-seq) of an [*enum-base*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#nt:enum-base) shall name an integral type; **any cv-qualification is ignored**.